# PT Field Type Checkboxes falling over when using {switch} in pairtag

Tags: pixelandtonic, field-pack, switch, pt-checkboxes

I'm currently using PT Field Type Checkboxes to echo out an entries list, which is working fine.
However when I combine this with the [{switch=""} tag](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#switch). This is blowing up and white screening the entire page when incorporating the switch tag.

```
<ul class="List--features">
    {cf_idea_features}
    <li class="Nav-item">
        {option} - {switch='foo|bar'}
    </li>
    {/cf_idea_features}
</ul>
```

The docs seem to suggest that switch is supported: https://github.com/pixelandtonic/pt_field_pack/blob/master/Docs/Pages/pt-checkboxes.html#L62

I'm running:
EE - v2.7.2
Field Pack - Checkboxes 2.1.1

Is this a bug or is switch implemented into Field Pack Checkboxes differently to expression engines channel loop?

Comment: It looks like you are reference documentation for the previous version of Fieldpack. The current docs are here: http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/fieldpack/fieldtypes/checkboxes/tags.html However it does look like switch tags should still be supported, so this may be a big. You may want to email support@pixelandtonic.com about this, as EESE isn't a place for bug reports.